# Form-driven query in MS Access using comma separated values as input? Is it possible?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have successfully queried data data in Access based on a value passed from a single text box on a form, but is there any way to pass a comma-delimited list into an IN query, or something to that effect?

The goal would be to search on more than a single-value criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to dynamically create your SQL in code, then feed the resultant query into the row source parameter.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that VBA is unavoidable then?

Comment: Unless you want to try using macros, which I personally always try to avoid, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If the comma list is numbers (1,5,723) then you can do:

```
ssql = "select * from table where field IN(" + scommalist + ")"
```

If the list is text, you have to parse it and put quotes around each value.